# how to loop through httprequest post variables in python

Tags: python, django, post, httprequest

How can you loop through the HttpRequest post variables in Django?

I have

```
for k,v in request.POST:
     print k,v
```

which is not working properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 112, accepted):

`request.POST` is a dictionary-like object containing all given HTTP POST parameters.

When you loop through `request.POST`, you only get the keys.

```
for key in request.POST:
    print(key)
    value = request.POST[key]
    print(value)
```

To retrieve the keys and values together, use the [`items`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.items) method.

```
for key, value in request.POST.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Note that `request.POST` can contain multiple items for each key. If you are expecting multiple items for each key, you can use [`lists`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.lists), which returns all values as a list.

```
for key, values in request.POST.lists():
    print(key, values)
```

For more information see the Django docs for [`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict).