# How to display all session keys and values in Django?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, session, django-sessions

How can I display all session keys and valuesv? I know that the value can be accessed with `request.session['key']` but I want to know if there are other values that are set by others or set automatically during user logins or similar other events..

Answer (score 50, accepted):

As referred by Daniel in comment.:

```
for key, value in request.session.items():
    print('{} => {}'.format(key, value))
```

helpful answer: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303336/how-to-loop-through-httprequest-post-variables-in-python) and [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict)

Answer (score 6):

You can try like this

```
 for key in request.session.keys():
        print "key:=>" + request.session[key]
```

Comment: correct me if iam wrong but this is giving me value of the keys instead of keys. for example. <QueryDict: {}>
key:=>johnson  # name of user logged in
key:=>a58f317f5ecc2eb686e576cda23372f1726c0b80
key:=>9
key:=>django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend

Comment: Really you want `for key, value in request.session.items(): print('{} => {}'.format(key, value))`.